# Should I use getter or setter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How about `react` work with `es6` `getter`/`setter`?

If the answer is yes, what's the advantages, is there some 'best practise'  work with `getter`/ `setter`?

And, if the answer is no, why?

In a `React` component class:

```
...
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.nameArr = Object.keys(this.props.nameMap);
}

getNames() {
   return Object.keys(this.props.nameMap);
}

get names() {
   return Object.keys(this.props.nameMap);
}

render() {
    const names = this.getNames();
    //or
    const namesTwo = this.names;
    //or
    const nameArr = this.nameArr;
}
...
```

what's the difference? I mean the final result. I can't figure out the difference.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your question and provide a concrete example? I don't understand why you would even ask that question. React doesn't restrict which JavaScript features you can use.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for anwser. I edit my question.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [What is the argument for using ES6 getters and setters over getProperty/setProperty convention?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32114468/218196) . Again, React doesn't care what you do. How you structure your code is completely up to you.

Comment: @GG.: Well, inside `class`es they are certainly from ES6 ;)

Comment: @FelixKling Indeed. :D