# What is the better way of changing a property of an instance of a class using JavaScript's class syntax?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a simple class that looks like this:

```
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then I initialize a single instance of that class:

```
const test = new Person('George');
```

But then I decide that I want to change the name of that instance and I wonder if I should create a function of that class that takes a name as an argument and then sets it like this:

```
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    const setName = (newName) => {
        this.name = newName;
    }
}
```

And then changing the name of the instance through the function like this:

```
test.setName('John');
```

Or just straight up change the name of the instance like this:

```
test.name = newName
```

Comment: JavaScript isn't Java. If you find out you need getter/setter logic later on, you can write [`get name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and/or [`set name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) _without_ changing the interface, you don't need to preemptively define `getName`/`setName`. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32114468/3001761.

Comment: Side note: If you declare your functions as fields instead of [prototype methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#prototype_methods), each instance of your class will have its own copy `setName` function and the function won't make it into the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is:

> What is the better way of changing a property of an instance of a
> class using JavaScript's class syntax?

the answer would be

> using [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)

```js
class Person {
  #name;//declare private property by prefix it with hash
  constructor(name) {
    this.#name = name;
  }
  set name(val) {
    this.#name = val;
  }

  get name() {
    return this.#name;
  }
}
let test = new Person('John');
test.name = "Mehdi";
console.log(test.name);
```

**Update:** *adding private properties to make sense using *getters and setters**

**Note:** *JS implement private properties in *ES2022*.*

Comment: I'd guess because writing a `get`ter and `set`ter that don't do anything beyond what direct property access would is pointless. The idea is that, unlike the methods, you don't have to define them until there's something they actually _do_.

Comment: Update adding private properties to make sense of using getters and setters!

Comment: I don't see how you can state that getters/setters are "better" - they are a tool for particular requirements ... the question does NOT have such requirements - updating the code to get/set a private property is "pretty", but still completely irrelevant to the question, and now you have a getter, a setter and a private property  .... all for zero benefit

Answer (score -1):

There are no public/private keywords for properties like in other languages.
Technically nothing is stopping you from doing it.

BUT

Using getters and setters allows you to add a level of abstraction.

For example, if later you want to add the fact that the names are not longer than 10 characters.
You will just have to modify the `setName()` function and it will affect all calls.
If you had used the direct method, you would have had to modify all the places where you used it.

Comment: _"you would have had to modify all the places where you used it"_ - that's not true, they can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Comment: Yes, but in his question it's "what's the best way between direct access or getter/setter by functions".
But i'm okay with you get/set keyword is the best way

Comment: lol @jonrsharpe, did I miss something? CodingMonkey was talking about the benefits of getters and setters, so ... you pointed out getters and setters as an alternative solution

Comment: @JaromandaX they're talking about e.g. _"the `setName()` function"_, which would be referred to as a setter but is **not** the same thing as `set name`.

Comment: Oh, @jonrsharpe, I really thought they were talking about the same thing, but I can see they may not have been. pardon my intrusion