# Setter/Getter on this

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, setter, getter

Is there anyway to make setter/getter only for class object? What I mean is, is there anyway to set `get`/`set` for `this` in class? For example:

```
class something {
    constructor() {
        // ...
    }
    get this() {
      return 'Fizz buzz'
    }
}

const somethingelse = new something
console.log(something) // "Fizz buzz"
```

This is what I want to get. If I want it to work exactly the same, I need to do `const {this} = new something`, which is what I don't want to use.

Comment: What you need is the equivalent to `toString()` function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the recommended way to customize toString? Using Symbol.toStringTag or overriding toString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42886953/whats-the-recommended-way-to-customize-tostring-using-symbol-tostringtag-or-ov)

Comment: Are you not getting any error for using this() ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what are ES6 class getter and setter actually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518139/what-are-es6-class-getter-and-setter-actually)

Comment: @Ahmad That was an example. I want to do way different thing.

Comment: @Manjeet Thakur I know what setter/getter is, I just wanted to know if it's possible to do it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no setters/getters for whole objects. A setter/getter always is a property. You assign/evaluate a reference to a property or variable, the object itself is not involved in that. You can't have an object that behaves like a primitive string when accessed. The closest you will get is something like

```
class Something {
    valueOf() {
        return 'Fizz buzz';
    }
}

const somethingelse = new Something;
console.log(something.valueOf()); // "Fizz buzz"
console.log(String(something)); // "Fizz buzz"
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, any reserved variable should not be overridden. So what you try to do is bad practice.

[How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

But if you want the this to point to a different scope you can easily do that locally with the `call` / `apply` functions or permanently with `bind` function.